# Can't install ownCloud update due to 'requires installation of untrusted packages' error in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: updates, 15.10, owncloud-client

I've got ownCloud Desktop Client installed and I've been being asked for months now to update ownCloud, but this update gets stuck at the 'Requires Installation of Untrusted Packages' system pop up dialogue. I've tried the answers from others with a similar problem, including retrieving key, apt-get update && upgrade, and many others, but nothing ever worked.
Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: What PPA did you install?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I guess it's Ubuntu Wily for amd64.

Comment: `owncloud-client` is not included by default in Ubuntu. What did you do to have it available?

Comment: I must've installed it through Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owncloud provides a guide on how to install the appropriate client here: https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:desktop&package=owncloud-client

For 15.04 it is:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_15.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud-client.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install owncloud-client
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the key for the owncloud repository with these two commands:

wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:ownCloud:desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/Release.key

sudo apt-key add - < Release.key

If that doesn't work for you, install y-ppa-manager from Synaptic, start PPA Manager from the dash, click the Advanced icon, and then choose import missing GPG keys.